# Как осуществить экстраполяцию изображения нулевого и первого порядка?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, img, pillow

Как осуществить экстраполяцию изображения нулевого и первого порядка с помощью opencv либо pillow?
Как я понимаю, мне нужно добавить в изображение некие элементы дабы изменить масштаб изображения, но как это сделать?

Comment: `экстраполяцию изображения нулевого и первого порядка` - а что это такое?

Comment: @MBo цитирую само задание: "Осуществить масштабирование изображений (экстраполяция нулевого и первого порядка)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ох, надо бы у препода выяснить, что он имел в виду.

Масштабирование в OpenCV выполняется с помощью [cv2.resize](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html)

Последний параметр - используемый метод. Возможно, INTER_NEAREST и INTER_LINEAR сойдут за нулевой и первый порядок